# How can I determine a variable's type in a vim function?

Tags: vim

Is there a way to check the type of a variable in vim? I need to check to make sure my functions argument is a number and am not sure how to go about it.

Comment: Type `:help type` in vim for a helpful legend on how to get the type of a variable: `let yourtype = type(your_variable)`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You're looking for `type(varname)`.

Note that explicit type checks are somewhat of a code smell (especially because the exact implicit type conversions done by Vim are not widely known); though I have to admit that sometimes they do make for a nice and short function interface.